# Google Apps Gmail SPF error

Tags: gmail, spf

I moved one client to Google Apps and it's been crazy! So many problems! And I never had these kind of problems

Client is using Outlook with Imap to manage his Google Apps Gmail account

Now when he sends email he got this kind of errors (for some addresses only):

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     spf-test@openspf.org

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 5.7.1 <spf-test@openspf.org>: Recipient address rejected: SPF Tests: Mail-From Result="pass": Mail From="nelson@samarfil.com" HELO name="mail-qa0-f45.google.com" HELO Result="none" Remote IP="209.85.216.45" (state 13).

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=samarfil.com; s=google;
        h=mime-version:x-originating-ip:date:message-id:subject:from:to
         :content-type;
        bh=bjpej8F5vAhPQFF4gZXUvUHOGuDj2lURhN5uAXH+4o4=;
        b=Gvhx7DYYlBFN1b0DQDDTq7Ll0tiGrrzMRGxVnIXOlbr8E3xhtY/lJGNcETSNDIblTT
         yQHNyBlnPZxm2AqN8aeJ60lM54QofFtEt4jZe4V0b9WkP8rBXl5KbEfADcJw3kgZQMN/
         8I0cpLYALe4YJ0PX8ZCXbtmFtd7m/Jmc/vKEo=
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=google.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:x-originating-ip:date:message-id:subject:from:to
         :content-type:x-gm-message-state;
        bh=bjpej8F5vAhPQFF4gZXUvUHOGuDj2lURhN5uAXH+4o4=;
        b=fdNJWqcTEv1GE5giglb7CBRbU5+1w0VBF8DGjAN2YlrNH624no/00JcJgu/cyw7eAs
         cIUUsU2vjMr7Kjjmc3xKbadMyF3A7b7u36l2t80aknCTdkSQuZ6yKT1EYY3INVUhue4Y
         Ml7qNaSiAPhNEHlzEttJn/OFYgPeG0rSC8OM5MyZdY6gE64bqrDLH/3chq/0M+yHclon
         hEYO7VytoV3BsNxr/HvEJEyNcHtTeX+WsVmxtNc5qgpxytbtReHEjl94auifz/YN16mg
         wyC7LUXIBfF3Tffs0NIL5ITwQIj4rSKNm/4N20bfWa6uPJn/30J1uvVoRjHegDtwYQyK
         yt8g==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.224.70.138 with SMTP id d10mr27073000qaj.12.1350404560884;
 Tue, 16 Oct 2012 09:22:40 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.49.24.205 with HTTP; Tue, 16 Oct 2012 09:22:40 -0700 (PDT)
X-Originating-IP: [94.133.34.4]
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2012 17:22:40 +0100
Message-ID: <CACP3cFsLYGus9Sr-cbuEFezBEXhdzSJ6gqGPOJr___UJARaBMw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject:
From: Nelson Santos <nelson@samarfil.com>
To: spf-test@openspf.org
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec51a81ec2793fc04cc2f90aa
X-Gm-Message-State: ALoCoQkvxVOP+l0d4ugZSxBkKf6IBmd7UYEWPxtodPNh+L5hBOkQD2zREymT1Eal1lH9JUSgBavX
```

I've already configured DNS to TXT record v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

what else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to receive this message, as that SPF test uses the error message to send back results. Are you experiencing errors when sending to other addresses?